# why is the transfer speed of scp in msys2 or cygwin limitted to 4MB

Tags: cygwin, git-bash, scp, openssh, msys2

I use scp in git bash to transfer files to remote servers . I found out that the transfer speed is limitted to 4MB. When I use scp in win32_openssh, the speed come up to 10MB.
Then I installed cygwin openssh for compare test, the scp speed is 4MB too.

So why is it limited? How to break it?

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a limitation from Cygwin itself, as discussed in this [2006 thread](http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/sshd-and-scp-sftp-slow-throughput-on-windows-machines-td7176.html)

> Unfortunately, the performance of the cygwin sshd server is very poor when
> it comes to copying large files.
>
> I have made this observation on several new and fast machines (3 GHz, 512 MB RAM, 100 MB/s Intel Pro network card) running with Windows XP or Windows 2003 Server.
> The best speed achievable was about 4 MB/s when copying a file from the SSH client to the SSH server;
> when doing it the other way round, the throughput was even worse, about 2.3
> MB/s.
> I tried it on three different machines running the newest version of
> cygwin's sshd und scp/sftp. The results were approximately the same.
> Neither the client's nor the server's processor was really busy. The CPU
> usage oscillated around 30-40%.

> Setting up the same scenario on linux yielded a completely different
> picture.
> Using the Knoppix disc 4.0.2 on the client and the server machine I
> easily achieved a throughput of 10.8 MB/ in both directions (pushing a file
> to the server or downloading a file from it).

That thread [points out to](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/2005-11/msg00897.html):

> The low speed of ssh and scp is not because of the encyption.
> The problem is the 64K limit for the window size in  the protocoll.